# How to add different types of values into arraylist<object>?

Tags: java

So basically I have a

```
public class Tournament {

private int [] par; // stores par for each hole in the golf course.
private ArrayList<Player> players; // stores the list of players.

public static final int NUMHOLES = 18;  // constant.
```

And

```
public ArrayList<Player> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}
```

But now I want to enter a name and handicap to the Players arrayList.

```
public void enter(String aName, int aHandicap) {

}
```

How do I create the enter() method?

I have tried

```
//players.add(aName); players.add(aHandicap);
//players.addAll(aName, aHandicap));
```

and no dice. ANY HELP APPRECIATED

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `players.add(new Player(aName, aHandicap))`

Comment: @Eran I was, thanks

Comment: @Paul I have gotten my answer, but will still read it, thanks

Comment: @RobBor Please note: I guess you wont see much updates any more. Please consider accepting that answer that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting your abstractions **wrong**. His name and handicap are a **property** of that player person. It is not a property of the list!

So, you add fields to your Player class, and then you initialize them either directly in the constructor, or you provide setter methods. Conceptually, the **name** should probably come in via the constructor - because the **name** should be immutable, and not change after creation of a Player. Whereas the **handicap** is likely to change; so there a **setter method** would be the better choice!

And then, you can iterate your list of Player objects, and call those setter methods on the **Player** objects, not the list.

In other words: your classes / objects are a **model** of reality. So your player class should represent those aspects of a "human player being" that make sense given the greater context of your model.

And even when you think that your Player class should **not** know about such things, you **still** create an abstraction, like:

```
public class EnhancedPlayer { // could extend Player
  that has those other fields
```

You see, your question would turn into: lets represent several pieces of information that *belong* together ... by putting them in different lists or so; and a "common" index would mean: stuff belongs together.

Finally, the direct answer: you can't do that; and you shouldn't do that. When you have a `List<Player>`, then you can only add player objects to that list!

Answer (score 2):

The `name` and the `handicap` of a `Player` are part of its identity such that they should be both fields of the class `Player` so:

Assuming that your class `Player` looks like:

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    private int handicap;

    public Player(final String name, final int handicap) {
        this.name = name;
        this.handicap = handicap;
    }

    // Getters (and setters if needed)
}
```

Then your method `enter` would be:

```
public void enter(String aName, int aHandicap) {
    players.add(new Player(aName, aName));
}
```

Comment: If I could kiss you, I would. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add Strings and numbers to a list of Players.

You need to create a Player first, then add the Player to the list. It won't auto-create a player for you just because you hand it the pieces needed to construct one.